# Error 1215 al crear una llave foránea

Tags: mysql, sql

Quisera que me ayudásen con un pequeño problema al intentar relacionar una tabla con otra en MySQL, este es mi código:

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
id int auto_increment not null,
nombre varchar(20) not null,
tipo varchar(10) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tipos(
id_tipo int auto_increment not null,
tipo varchar(10) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (id_tipo)
);

ALTER TABLE productos ADD CONSTRAINT fk_protip_database FOREIGN KEY (tipo) REFERENCES tipos(id_tipo);
```

Todo bien hasta que se ejecuta la sentencia para crear la llave foránea. Allí es donde me salta el error 1215.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para definir una llave foránea entre 2 columnas, estas deben ser del mismo tipo. En este caso, no lo son:

- `productos.tipo`: `varchar(10)`
- `tipos.id_tipo`: `int`

Ajusta el tipo de una de las 2 columnas para que queden iguales.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!
Como no me habia dado cuenta de ese pequeño detalle antes??? Mil gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Ese error se da habitualmente en cuatro casos (no exclusivamene):
1) Los tipos de columna no corresponden entre PK y FK.
2) Se intenta una FK desde un campo simple a una clave compuesta.
3) Existen datos en la tabla con la FK que no existen en la tabla referida (valores ilegales).
4) El orden de creacion de las tablas es incorrecto (las que tienen FK deben ser las últimas).