# ERROR 1215 mysql

Tags: mysql

llevo comiéndome la cabeza sobre esto durante 1 hora al menos y he no encuentro ningún fallo y me pasa lo mismo en dos tablas diferentes, si me podéis ayudar os lo agradezco.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por si no veis la imagen el codigo es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE INCIDENCIAS (
      cod_incidencia int(5) primary key,
      gravedad varchar(10),
      descripcion varcahr(50));

CREATE TABLE MANTENIMIENTO (
      id int(5),
      idiomas varchar(50),
      cod_camping int(5),
      foreign key (cod_camping) reference Camping(cod_camping),
      primary key (id, cod_camping));

CREATE TABLE NOTIFICA (
       cod_incidencia int(5),
       id_mantenimiento int(5),
       foreign key (cod_incidencia) references Incidencias(cod_incidencia), 
foreign key (id_mantenimiento) references Mantenimiento (id),
primary key (cod_incidencia, id_mantenimiento));
```

Comment: podrías poner el código como texto, para que podamos ayudarte, saludos.

Comment: Procura mostrar la estructura de las tablas y la consulta SQL _como texto, con formato_, ya que [no todos pueden visualizar las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). ¿Llegaste a fijarte en [estas preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=1215)?

Comment: El error que te da es el mismo descrito en este enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769926/foreign-key-in-mysql-as-composite-primary-key Estás intentando montar una FK sobre una tabla cuya PK también es compuesta. Un saludo!

Comment: Explica brevemente el contenido del enlace que proporcionas: ten en cuenta que puede que el contenido no esté disponible más adelante, volviendo inválida esta respuesta. Lee [answer].

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta, es un comentario y, además, deberías tramitarlo pulsando en "Cerrar" > Duplicadas y allí pegar el enlace para que se tramite el cierre por duplicidad.

Comment: @OscarGarcia estoy de acuerdo con lo que indicas, pero ahí está el problema, llevo poco tiempo, tengo "poca reputación" por lo que no puedo añadir comentarios directamente... :)

Comment: de todas formas creo que no es mi problema, lo e visto y lo e probado pero me falla tambien

Comment: Imagino que revisaste las preguntas de la búsqueda... La pista está en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/122503) ;)

Comment: ya vi cual creo que es el posible fallo  pero no lo se arreglar (soy nuevo en mysql) el fallo supongo que se relacionara con lo siguiente  "Se intenta una FK desde un campo simple a una clave compuesta."

Comment: Y la tabla Camping, yo acabo de probar el query sin la tabla Camping y todo correcto, puedes verlo en este  [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10b43e/1/0)

Comment: si funciona, pero la tabla camping la necesito si o si, porque lo que pase es una pequeña parte de la base de datos

Comment: Agrega el query de la tabla Camping para probar

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el códio que te haga falta para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: creo que me funciono, añadi el camping y la tabla empleados ya que sin esta camping tampoco funcionaba y me hizo la query, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a0640/3/0 pero quitando la foreign key de camping en la tabla mantenimiento

Comment: ya esta, ya vi el fallo en esta query a ver si veo como hacerlo en el mysql, muchas gracias por la ayuda ;)

Comment: El error es por que en la tabla camping no has definido cod_camping como primary key, mira ahora y sin quitar campos [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ca08c/1/0)

Comment: si, me percate de eso unos minutos despues de enviar el resultado, y viendo la query y comparandolo con el mysql detecte el fallo, basicamente en la tabla de mantenimiento, en la definición de primary key, estaban al reves los campos y ahora funciono

Comment: muchas gracias a todos